# VB passing drop down values to a query in another window

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am building a small Visual Basic app in Visual Studio 2010 which, as a web developer, I'm not very proficient with yet so maybe you guys can help me out!

I just need help taking the selected values from 3 list boxes and passing them to another Windows form to generate a query and display the query results in a table. I specifically need help on how to pass the values to the next form, and how to have a Data Grid View display the results of the dynamically created query.

Thanks in advance for any help! I'm a noob to Visual Studio and Visual Basic so excuse me if this is a really easy question!

**Update:** Here is the code from my first form.

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'Labdataset.Lab' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.LabTableAdapter.Fill(Me.Labdataset.Lab)
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'Buildingdataset.Building' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.BuildingTableAdapter.Fill(Me.Buildingdataset.Building)
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'WilfordDataSet.Software' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.SoftwareTableAdapter.Fill(Me.WilfordDataSet.Software)

End Sub

Private Sub ListBox3_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles LabList.SelectedIndexChanged

End Sub


Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Form2.param1 = SoftwareList.SelectedItem
    Form2.param2 = BuildingList.SelectedItem
    Form2.param3 = LabList.SelectedItem


End Sub
```

Here is my code from the second form
    Public Class Form2

```
Private _param1 As String
Private _param2 As String
Private _param3 As String


Public WriteOnly Property param1 As String
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _param1 = value
    End Set
End Property


Public WriteOnly Property param2 As String
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _param2 = value
    End Set
End Property

Public WriteOnly Property param3 As String
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _param3 = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second form, change the constructor of the class like this:

```
Public Sub New(ByVal param1 As String, ByVal param2 As String, ByVal param3 As String)
    InitializeComponent()

    MessageBox.Show(param1) 'Just to show that the parameter is correct.
    'Should be replaced by methods that process your query.
End Sub
```

In the event handler that should be invoke after clicking the button(or any other trigger), you can pass the parameters like:

```
Private Sub buttonName_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim myForm = New Form2(ListBox1.SelectedItem, ListBox2.SelectedItem, ListBox3.SelectedItem)
    myForm.Show()
End Sub
```

Then you can proceed on handling the query.
This is just one way of doing it. If you want(but a little dirtier approach), you can just declare the variables in Form2 and access it via the first form. As an example:

```
Form2.param1
```

**Update:**
To elaborate the second approach, in the second form you can write just after the class name

```
    Private _param1 As String
    Private _param2 As String
    Private _param3 As String

    Public WriteOnly Property param1 As String
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _param1 = value
        End Set
    End Property

'Same with the other parameters...
```

Then access the parameters in the first form via

```
 Form2.param1 = ListBox1.SelectedItem
'And so on
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response, I've been working on it for a couple hours now with your help and it's not working yet, but I think it's my fault, not your suggestions. I keep getting an error that says "Conversion from type 'DataRowView' to type 'String' is not valid." and it highlights "Form2.param1 = ListBox1.SelectedItem" saying that's what's causing the problem. Is it an issue if my list boxes are populated by datasets? I feel like that's causing the problem

Comment: @Pierce Where is that DataRowView came from? can you update your question by posting that code?

Comment: Yes, I posted the code for both forms that I have right now. But the DataRowView only shows up in the error message I get when I run the app, select 3 values from the list boxes and click the button to go to the next form.

Comment: @Pierce Just a try: Form2.param1 = Convert.ToString((ListBox1.SelectedIndex))

Comment: That worked! Thanks! All I need to do now is get a view to display the results of the query with the 3 parameters in it

Comment: Ok great, I'll do that.